# Find div by given class and data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html, addclass

I want to find div by given class and data-id but following line doesn't work (In this example class is `lesson` and `data-id` is variable)

```
$('div.lesson[data-id=' + htag + ']').addClass('underline');
```

What am I missing?

## Update

Full function looks like that

```
        LoadLessons(cid);
        LoadQuestions(lid);
        $('div.course[data-id=' + cid + ']').addClass('underline');
        $('div.lesson[data-id=' + lid + ']').addClass('underline');
```

Load.. functions are **ajax** calls. And class must affect content which returned by ajax call.  First addclass works but second not.

Comment: If these are ajax calls, are you setting the underline class in your success callback? As it look in your code example, the addClass code is being executed immediately following after kicking off your ajax requests and not after a response has been received. That is if these elements are being inserted in the DOM dynamically with the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/MeNt2/1/)**

```
$('div[class=lesson][data-id="' + htag + '"]').addClass('underline');
```

Comment: Not necessary; you're actually introducing a descendant combinator in fact.

Comment: problem is content loading with ajax. I think it's because content loads after this function

Comment: @pimvdb I think it picks up the correct element update my answer with live demo

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes to attribute selector, like this:

```
$('div.lesson[data-id="' + htag + '"]').addClass('underline');
```

Comment: That depends on his doctype and if there are spaces in attribute selector values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing ajax calls, you should put your code in the `complete` callback of those ajax calls. Because you don't know how long those ajax calls will take.